# what is kgsearch.properties? Cant apply google knowledge graph API using Java

Tags: java, eclipse, google-knowledge-graph

This is my code executed on Eclipse 
It is copied from here:
https://developers.google.com/knowledge-graph/

with all libraries installed, the program can be compiled successfully, but the program terminated with 
java.io.FileNotFoundException: kgsearch.properties (No such file or directory) error.  How can I get the following sample code work on my eclipse ?

```
import com.google.api.client.http.GenericUrl;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequestFactory;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpResponse;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpTransport;

import com.jayway.jsonpath.JsonPath;

import org.json.simple.JSONArray;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.util.Properties;

public class mainS {
  public static Properties properties = new Properties();
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
      properties.load(new FileInputStream("kgsearch.properties"));

      HttpTransport httpTransport = new NetHttpTransport();
      HttpRequestFactory requestFactory = httpTransport.createRequestFactory();
      JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
      GenericUrl url = new GenericUrl("https://kgsearch.googleapis.com/v1/entities:search");
      url.put("query", "Taylor Swift");
      url.put("limit", "10");
      url.put("indent", "true");
      url.put("key", properties.get("API_KEY"));
      HttpRequest request = requestFactory.buildGetRequest(url);
      HttpResponse httpResponse = request.execute();
      JSONObject response = (JSONObject) parser.parse(httpResponse.parseAsString());
      JSONArray elements = (JSONArray) response.get("itemListElement");
      for (Object element : elements) {
        System.out.println(JsonPath.read(element, "$.result.name").toString());
      }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
      ex.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes because `kgsearch.properties` might not exists.
Create the file and enter your API_KEY there.
The file should look like
`API_KEY = <your_key_here>`

Once you have created and saved the file use the following code snippet

```
File file = new File("C:/your/path/here/", "kgsearch.properties");
properties.load(new FileInputStream(file));
```

It should work afterwords

Read about a similar problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34569751/implementing-google-knowledge-graph-on-android) and example [here](https://github.com/debmalya/google-knowledge-graph-api/tree/master/kgsearch/src/main/resource)